# bottom selection view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to select a bottom horizontal list of items. and the data should be changed for each item for selection(like bottom navigation)

I tried with collection view but it's​ not working

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Also the problem statement is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Be nice, and check out our https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Don't assume everyone understands your issue with the given details. Add more details such as screenshots, the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).

> The tab bar interface displays tabs at the bottom of the window for selecting between the different modes and for displaying the views for that mode. This class is generally used as-is, but may also be subclassed.
>
> Each tab of a tab bar controller interface is associated with a custom view controller. When the user selects a specific tab, the tab bar controller displays the root view of the corresponding view controller, replacing any previous views.

Comment: no. the mechanism is same. but i need to customize the bar dynamically ,